# SQL SELECT statement with users, roles and rights

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Lets say that I have tables:

1. Users
2. Users_in_Roles
3. Roles
4. Rights_in_Roles
5. Rights

Keys are standard( UserFk, RoleFk, RightFk)

The question is: how to get all users that are in role with right X (id = 100)

I Have no idea how to touch this problem. Please help and sorry for my english.

```
SELECT [dbo].[System_Users].[Id]
  ,[UserName]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[LastName]
  ,[Email]
  ,RoleFk
  ,[dbo].[System_Roles].Name
  FROM [dbo].[System_Users]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[System_Roles_System_Users]
ON [dbo].[System_Roles_System_Users].UserFk = [dbo].[System_Users].Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[System_Roles]
ON [dbo].[System_Roles].Id = [dbo].[System_Roles_System_Users].RoleFk

WHERE ?
```

---

I tryied sth like that, could you tell me what iw wrong?

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT System_Users.Id,
System_Users.FullName
FROM System_Users
INNER JOIN Dict_Rights_System_Users
ON System_Users.Id = Dict_Rights_System_Users.UserFk
INNER JOIN System_Roles_System_Users
ON System_Roles_System_Users.UserFk = System_Users.Id
WHERE
RightFk = 136
OR
136 IN (SELECT Dict_Rights_System_Roles.RightFk FROM Dict_Rights_System_Roles WHERE             
Dict_Rights_System_Roles.RoleFk = System_Roles_System_Users.RoleFk)
ORDER BY System_Users.FullName ASC
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Comment: Could you inform us about the layout of the tables please?

Comment: Ok, i'll post my tryings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Users u
WHERE   EXISTS (
        SELECT  ur.RoleFk
        FROM    Users_in_Roles ur
        WHERE   u.UserPk = ur.UserFk
        AND     EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    Rights_in_Roles rr
                    WHERE   rr.RoleFk = ur.RoleFk
                    AND     rr.RightFk = 100
                )
)
OR  EXISTS (

        SELECT  1
        FROM    Users_Rights uri
        WHERE   u.UserPk = uri.UserFk 
        AND     uri.RightFk = 100
)
```

Note that the above query doesn't return `RoleFk` and `Name` for the role.

Another approach would be:

```
SELECT   u.Id
        ,u.UserName
        ,u.FirstName
        ,u.LastName
        ,u.Email
        ,rr.RoleFk
        ,r.Name
FROM    Users u

        -- get users that are in role that has right
LEFT JOIN   
        Users_in_Roles ur ON
        ur.UserFk = u.UserPk
LEFT JOIN   
        Rights_in_Roles rr ON
        rr.RoleFk = ur.RoleFk
AND     rr.RightFk = 100
LEFT JOIN   
        Rights r ON
        r.RolePk = rr.RoleFk

        -- get users that have a right granted to them directly
LEFT JOIN
        Users_Rights uri ON
        u.UserPk = uri.UserFk 
AND     uri.RightFk = 100

WHERE   rr.RoleFk IS NOT NULL OR uri.UserFk IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I didnt say before but there is one more condition. User must have a right or user must be in role with the right (id = 100). There is one more table joins users with rights.

Comment: Could you tray make this by Joins?

Comment: Everything is Ok, I used your first solution. Thank you:)

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm glad it helped, I removed my first solution because it wasn't returning the `RoleFk` and `Name` of the role fields.

Comment: I was returning these columns only for test, I need only User Id and UserName ;]

Answer (score 3):

You will need to `JOIN` the tables on the key relationships. The basic structure will be:

```
select u.Id, 
  u.UserName,
  u.FirstName,
  u.LastName,
  u.Email,
  r.RoleFk,
  r.Name RoleName,
  rt.Name RightName
from users u
inner join users_in_roles ur
  on u.id = ur.userfk
inner join roles r
  on ur.rolefk = r.id
inner join rights_in_roles rr
  on r.rolefk = rr.rolefk
inner join rights rt
  on rr.rightfk = rt.id
where rt.id = 100
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax here is a great reference:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)